# Ubuntu ISO file for version 16.04.4

Tags: 16.04

I can update to Ubuntu 16.04.4 through but i'm wondering will there have the iso files for this version or just updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iso files are at the iso tracker now (for testing purposes). See this link and links from it,

[**16.04.4** at iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/386/builds)

We can expect that they will arrive soon (March 1, 2018) at the usual web sites for Ubuntu iso files, for example

[releases.ubuntu.com/](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

Edit: I can confirm that you can find 16.04.4 at [releases.ubuntu.com/](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) now.

Comment: then they will update the iso to release.ubuntu.com but do we have ETA? im sorry im new ^^

Comment: Unless a showstopping bug is found, the current iso files will be copied or linked to the usual web sites. I don't know exactly when this will happen, but you can download the files now from the iso tracker and if you use the `zsync` or `rsync` method, there is an automatic checksum procedure, so that you can be sure to get a correct copy.